# Using R, How do I copy the tibble to an element of the list. for example, each element like ff[i] have a nibble at each i

Tags: r

Use vector() to create an empty vector called ff that is of mode “list” and length 9. Now write a for() loop to loop over the 9 files in dfiles and for each (i) read the file in to a tibble, and change the column names to x and y, and (ii) copy the tibble to an element of your list ff.

dfiles is a directory which has different files.

This is what I did.

```
ff <- vector(mode = "list", length = 9)
length <- length(dfiles)
for (i in 1:length) {
  study <- read_csv(dfiles[i])
  names(study)[1] <- "x"
  names(study)[2] <- "y"
  ff[i] <- c(study)
  print(head(ff[i]))
}
```

```
[[1]]
  [1] -0.989532202 -0.052799402  0.823610903 -0.255509103 -0.220684347
  [6]  0.307726791 -0.060013253 -0.555652890 -0.138615019  1.882839792
 [11]  0.873668680 -0.914597073 -1.244917622 -0.359982241  1.328774701
 [16]  0.292679118 -0.701505237  0.882234568 -0.133370389 -1.120678499
 [21]  0.461192454  1.524142810  0.434468298  0.192000371 -0.656243128
 [26]  0.568398531 -1.070570535 -1.653149024 -0.043352768 -0.034593506
 [31]  2.365055532 -1.216347308  0.170906323  0.805053094  1.050592844
 [36] -0.010724485 -0.743256141 -0.065784052  1.939755992  0.482739008
 [41] -2.044477073  1.423459129  0.540502661 -0.033571772 -0.017863621
 [46] -0.149789720  0.256559481 -0.503866933  0.277011252 -0.931356025
 [51]  0.200146875  1.106837421  0.509206114  1.033749676 -1.090868762
 [56]  0.054792784  0.617250303 -1.068004868  1.565814337 -1.034808011
 [61]  0.164518709  0.151832330  0.121670302 -0.210424584  0.449936787
 [66] -1.031164492 -1.289364188 -0.654568638 -0.057324104  1.256747820
 [71]  1.587454140  0.319481463  0.381591623 -0.243644884  0.048053084
 [76] -1.404545861  0.289933729 -0.535553582  0.334678773 -0.345981339
 [81] -0.661615735 -0.219111377 -0.366904911  1.094578208  0.209208082
 [86]  0.432491426 -1.240853586  1.496821710  0.159370441 -0.856281403
 [91]  0.309046645  0.870434030 -1.383677138  1.690106970 -0.158030705
 [96]  1.121170781  0.072261319 -0.332422845 -1.834920047 -1.100172219
[101] -0.041340300  0.827852545 -1.881678654  1.375441112  1.398990464
[106] -1.143316256  0.472300562 -1.033639213 -0.125199979  0.928662739
[111]  0.868339648 -0.849174604 -0.386636454 -0.976163571  0.339543660
[116] -1.559075164 -2.629325442  1.469812282  2.273472913 -0.455033540
[121]  0.761102487 -0.007502784  1.474313800
```

and the following error.

```
1: In ff[i] <- c(study) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In ff[i] <- c(study) :
```

I was expecting that it'll still have column names so I am not sure how to fix it and where I am going wrong.

Comment: Maybe `ff[i] <- study`...without concatenating because it coerces it to a list

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In ff[i] <- study :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.                                       It still gives this warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Was supposed to use double brackets.
ff[[i]] <- study would fix the problem.